# Python Anaconda: 1) установка; 2) необходимость для Machine Learning

Tags: python, anaconda, scikit-learn

Два вопроса по Python Anaconda

1. OS Ubuntu 16.04. Надо ли перед установкой PA сносить имеющиеся Python и библиотеки (pandas, numpy, mathplotlib и т.д.)? Если нет, то обновятся ли библиотеки на новые версии? Бывают ли конфликты?
2. Начал изучать Machine Learning. Некоторые граждане пишут, что крайне желательно поставить PA т.к. будут Jupyter Notebook, все установленные библиотеки и ещё ряд важных удобств. Наличие PA действительно сильно упростит жизнь именно в этом смысле?

Вопросы простые, так что приму ответы типа да\нет.

Comment: Нет/нет. Используйте виртуальное окружение `virtualenv` это прежде всего, либы это только инструмент, для `machine learning` только либ маловато, надо понимать что происходит внутри и почему

Comment: Anaconda по умолчанию устанавливается в отедльную директорию, поэтому ничего сносить не нужно и мешать она не будет. Если скачаете последнюю версию, все модули идущие будут иметь версию новее. Да с anacond'ой ставится большой набор библиотек необходимых для машинного обучения и это будет проще чем ставить все руками.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как уже прокомментировали коллеги Anaconda ставится в отдельную директорию (вы решаете куда) и не пересекается с "системным" Python.

Если все сделать правильно то никаких сложностей/проблем не возникнет.

Вот приблизительный алгоритм установки Anaconda под UNIX*:

Установка Anaconda:

```
bash Anaconda3-X.X.X-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Обновление `conda`:

```
conda update conda
```

Создание собственного VirtualEnv (имя окружения - `ml` [machine learning], версия Python - 2.7):

```
conda create -n ml python=2.7 anaconda
```

PS можно создать сразу несколько окружений/сред для разных версий, например:

```
conda create -n ml27 python=2.7 anaconda
conda create -n ml35 python=3.5 anaconda
conda create -n ml36 python=3.6 anaconda
```

Активирование окружения:

```
conda activate ml
```

Установка дополнительных пакетов/модулей для определенного окружения (VirtualEnv):

```
conda install -n ml [package]
```

Для работы в скриптах можно создать файл окружения (назовем его: `$HOME/.ml_env`):

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my/own/python_libs
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/lib:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Потом в SHELL скриптах добавляем след. строки:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $HOME/.ml_env
source activate ml
```

---

Полезные ссылки:

- https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Действительно пользоваться Anaconda очень удобно по целому ряду причин:

- полностью независимая от системного Python среда, которую легко настроить под себя, перенести на другую машину, удалить или переустановить и при этом никак не затрагивая и не "ломая" системный Python
- все устанавливаемые модули совместимы друг с другом и протестированы - об этом заботится Continuum Analytics
- очень много полезных модулей (особенно для тех кто занимается machine learning) уже установлены по умолчанию

Comment: Спасибо! Из ваших ответов можно делать отдельный туториал.

Comment: @БорисМирский, спасибо !