# Организация библиотек python на Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Вопрос по организации библиотек в питоне.

Исходные данные:
python3 /pip3

В момент установки и загрузки пакетов получилось так - что эти пакеты сейчас лежат в директориях `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`  и `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dst-packages`

Причем, как я понял pip3 качает во вторую директорию.

На текущий момент так получилось - что версии пакетов в обеих директориях разные - собирать правильно не представляется возможным.

Но удалить "как бы не используемые" пакеты из  `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` не представляется возможным - после этого pip3 начинает ругаться при попытке чего-то установить -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
```

и т.д.

Т.е. появляется еще третья директория в `home` `.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip` - на которую ссылается pip3 и которая ссылается на `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

В общем - какой-то бардак.

Как аккуратно и правильно сделать - чтобы все библиотеки лежали и обновлялись только в одной директории?  Как вообще правильно организовать работу? В java все просто - все пакеты качаются в .m2 - а тут мне кажется все довольно запутанно.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал "не трогать" (не ломать) системный питон. [Лучше поставить Anaconda в указанную вами директорию и создать независимый VirtualEnv для каждого проекта...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685123/python-anaconda-1-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-machine-learning)

Comment: А если нет никакой необходимости в дистрибутиве Анаконды, то можно просто собрать питон из исходников, например, по умолчанию в `/usr/local/lib`, а `pip` использовать с флагом `--user` для установки всего стороннего в домашнюю директорию.

Comment: Спасибо! Решил сделать так - использовать свой питон + virtualEnv ( без анаконды и т.д.) - все зарабатало и получилось удобно и независимо от кучи мусора в системе. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: не ясно что и почему вы пытались установить. Для разных задач, разные подходы работают. Системный менеджер пакетов в свои места разбрасывает библиотеки, `pip --user` в другие, `pip` внутри virtualenv в третьи. virtualenvwrapper позволяет несколькими virtualenv управлять. pythonz/pyenv позволяет версиями Питона управлять. pipsi использует pip и virtualenv, чтобы изолировать каждое приложение в своём окружении. conda позволяет управлять и Питон-пакетами и С зависимостями и сами версии Питона выбирать. Есть и другие инструменты. *Выбирайте в зависимости от задачи подходящий инструмент.*

Comment: Python3.6 из исходников может работать без virtualenv в отдельной папке