# как поставить requests модуль на macOS

Tags: python, macos, установка, requests

Начал учить, что такое Python и возник вопрос с модулем requests. У меня MacOS. Я установил модуль

```
sudo pip install requests
```

Но теперь, когда я пытаюсь запустить программу с импортированным модулем без sudo, я получаю ошибку

```
ImportError: No module named requests
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: а питон точно один в системе?

Comment: @gil9red безусловно

Comment: все же попробуйте вместо pip попробовать pip3. Проверка не повредит.

Comment: мне кажется лучше [поставить Anaconda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685169/211923) и не менять системный Python - его легко сломать, а починить не всегда так просто

Comment: что происходит если выполнить `python -mrequests.certs` до/после `python -mpip install requests`  с/без `--user` с/без `sudo`.

Comment: sudo easy_install pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@StereoFlo: проблема оказалась в том, что я использовал python из сборки MAMP. В свою очередь, под sudo глобально запускался системный python. Ни каких ошибок у меня нет

Answer (score 0):

если python3 : то попробуй pip3 install requests

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/232582)

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, почему? `pip3` вместо `pip` - вроде вполне ответ?

Comment: @Qwertiy автор ответа не уверен в своем ответе, по-этому мне показалось, что такой ответ тянет максимум на комментарий.