# Как изменить версию python для apache?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

На ubuntu стоит python 3.5 а мне нужен 3.6. Установил его из репозитория и теперь не знаю как подсунуть его в мод wsgi. Судя по логам сервер использует 3.5 и вылетает с ошибкой 500.

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685123/python-anaconda-1-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-2-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-machine-learning)

Comment: И как эти вопросы связаны?

Comment: Поставьте Anaconda, создайте себе виртуальное окружение с нужной версией Python и забудьте о подобных проблемах

Comment: Вы сейчас серьёзно? Нафига мне Anaconda? Мне нужно чтобы apche использовал python 3.6 и всё. Мне не нужны все пакеты из Anaconda на 200+ мб.

Comment: Я этот вопрос видел много раз на англоязычном SO. Люди "апгрейдили" системный питон и через время те же люди задавали вопросы как починить системный питон после "апгрейда"... Удачи вам :-) PS Miniconda должна быть поменьше

Answer (score 0):

пробуйте установить пакет

```
yum install python36u-mod_wsgi
```

Comment: А в ubuntu какой пакет. Такого в репозиторих нет.

Comment: `wget https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm`
    `rpm -Uvh ius-release*rpm`
    `yum --enablerepo=ius-dev install python36u-mod_wsgi`