# После переустановки tensorflow ничего не работает

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

У меня Win7-64, Python 3.6. Без GPU. ПОсле upgrade  tensorflow до1.8, этот маленький текст даёт ошибки

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site- >packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 14, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126,
>   in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) File "", line 978, in _gcd_import File "", line 961, in
>   _find_and_load File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 648, in _load_unlocked
>       File "", line 560, in module_from_spec
>       File "", line 922, in create_module File "", line 205, in >_call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed with error code >-1073741795
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 17, in _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 16, in swig_import_helper return
>   importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') File
>   "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "K:\Python\testTensorflow.py", line 1, in import tensorflow as tf File
>   "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 24, in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint:
>   disable=unused-import File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line
>   49, in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow File
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent
>   call last): File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\pythonpywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 14, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126,
>   in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) File "", line 978, in _gcd_import File "", line 961, in
>   _find_and_load File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 648, in _load_unlocked
>    File "", line 560, in module_from_spec
>    File "", line 922, in create_module File "", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 17, in _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 16, in swig_import_helper return
>   importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') File
>   "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>   See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить и снова установить. Если не получится, то установите старую версию (в pip можно указывать конкретные версии)

Comment: Всё это я уже делал. Была 1.7 .
Переустанавливал туда-сюда неоднократно

Comment: Такая же проблема https://stackoverflow.com/a/46451281/5909792 Посмотреть варианты: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

Comment: очень советую [установить Anaconda и создать отдельное окружение для ML задач](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685123/python-anaconda-1-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-machine-learning/685169#685169). В будущем вы будете обновлять одно окружение не рискуя сломать/порушить что-то еще...

Comment: Я и сам тоже пришёл к такому мнению. Но сейчас мне надо пока заткнуть как то эту дыру и поскорей.

Comment: Установил Anaconda3 (5-2). По рекомендации
https://www.asozykin.ru/deep_learning/2018/03/30/TensorFlow-Anaconda-Pip-Install.html установил tensorflow:
 pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
запустил тот же тест:
    import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))

Comment: Установил Anaconda3 (5-2). По рекомендации
https://www.asozykin.ru/deep_learning/2018/03/30/TensorFlow-Anaconda-Pip-Install.html установил tensorflow:
 pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
запустил тот же тест:

    import tensorflow as tf
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
    sess = tf.Session()
    print(sess.run(hello))

и получил прежний результат:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",..далее см исх. сообщение