# Не импортируется Keras в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook

Когда я запускаю `import keras` в ячейке Jupyter Notebook, он падает с соообщением *The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.*

Keras                  2.2.0

jupyter                1.0.0
jupyter-client         5.2.3
jupyter-console        5.2.0
jupyter-core           4.4.0
jupyterlab             0.32.1
jupyterlab-launcher    0.10.5

Python                 3.6.6

Вывод консоли

```
kraamis@debian [~]$ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 27 2018, 14:44:17) 
[GCC 8.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
Недопустимая инструкция
```

Comment: Просто в консоли Python попробуйте импортировать, что будет?

Comment: Добавил в пост вывод консоли

Comment: После сообщения "Недопустимаю инструкция" в bash выкидывает? Предположение: установленная версия Tensorflow не совпадает по битности с битностью системы.

Comment: Нет, дело было в том, что у меня процессор старый и новые версии библиотек не поддерживает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тяжеловесов наподобие TensorFlow, Keras, etc. лучше [устанавливать в VirtualEnv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685169/211923), а не в системный Python.

Шаги для создания VirtualEnv:

установить Anaconda:

```
bash Anaconda3-X.X.X-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

обновление `Conda`:

```
conda update conda
```

Создание собственного VirtualEnv (имя окружения - ml [machine learning], версия Python - 3.6):

```
conda create -n ml python=3.6 \
  anaconda ipython jupyter cython matplotlib scikit-learn openpyxl pyarrow \
  lxml beautifulsoup4 html5lib sqlalchemy pymysql psycopg2 fastparquet \
  pandas-datareader opencv nltk xlrd xlwt xlsxwriter networkx  pyodbc gensim
```

Устанавливаем модули из репозитория `conda-forge`:

```
conda install -n ml -c conda-forge scikit-image keras
```

PS если вы вдруг что-то сломаете в VirtualEnv - вы всегда можете его пересоздать, не затрагивая системный Python. А еще лучше клонировать ваш рабочий VirtualEnv и тестировать новые версии модулей в нем:

```
conda create --name ml --clone ml_test
conda update --all -n ml_test -y
```