# Почему у меня не удаляется python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, macos, ос

Как удалить Python полностью с macOS Mojave?

Мне нужно установить Python 3, но до этого у меня была версия Python 2. Я пробовал удалить папку `Python` в `/Library` и установить заново, но это не помогло:

```
python -V
```

все равно выводится:

> Python 2.7.10.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/5909792 ?

Comment: @gil9red Не помогло

Comment: Не думаю, что вы попробовали `все` предложенные в ответах действия :) кст, раз вам нужен питон3, то поставьте его и не парьтесь. Если нужно его запустить, то `python3`, если нужен `pip`, то `pip3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Не надо удалять или изменять системный, являющийся частью `OS`, Python - в системе могут быть Python скрипты, которые перестанут работать правильно если изменить Python 2 --> Python 3 или "сломать" Python.

Лучше всего поставить [последнюю версию пакета Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos), [создать несколько виртуальных окружений (`VirtualEnv`) с нужными версиями Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685169/211923) и убедиться что в переменной `PATH` для вашего пользователя впереди стоит путь к нужному вам вирт. окружению.

Таким образом вы не будете зависеть от системного Python и сможете иметь несколько независимых окружений.