# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: - keras - pil

Tags: python, keras

Пытаюсь сделать пример https://becominghuman.ai/building-an-image-classifier-using-deep-learning-in-python-totally-from-a-beginners-perspective-be8dbaf22dd8 , 
Получаю ошибку

```
File "\keras_preprocessing\image.py", line 496, in load_img
raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL.
```

При попытке поставить Pil

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:   - keras   - pil
```

Установка Pillow не решает проблему, пробовал c Anaconda на питоне 2.7 и 3.6

Comment: попробуйте удалить `keras` и `PIL` и установить их снова через Anaconda: `conda install PIL keras`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую установить последнюю версию Anaconda и создать несколько виртуальных окружений.

Пример:

1. устанавливаем последнюю версию Anaconda (3.7)
2. обновляем `conda`

   ```
   conda update conda
   ```
3. создаем виртуальное окружения (`ml` - Machine Learning):

   ```
   conda create --name ml python=3.6 anaconda ipython jupyter keras
   ```

если ваша видеокарта поддерживается `Cuda 9`, то лучше установить `keras-gpu`, вместо `keras`, чтобы обучение запускалось на GPU, а не на CPU:

```
    conda create --name ml python=3.6 anaconda ipython jupyter keras-gpu
```

4. далее используем созданное окружение для работы:

в Windows:

```
    activate ml
```

в *NIX системах:

```
    source activate ml
```

PS в [данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685169/211923) есть примеры настройки SHELL скриптов для работы в VirtualEnv...

Comment: Сделал все описанное выше, но в проекте pyCharm не появился keras (в Conda executable выбирал путь к ml), где можно почитать как работать с такими окружениями ?