# Ошибка: module 'spacy.lang.en' has no attribute '__all__'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, nlp, spacy

Делаю в Anaconda prompt с правами администратора.:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy

\Anaconda3\python.exe -m spacy download en

Anaconda3\python.exe -m spacy download xx
```

Открываю Jupyter и делаю:

```
import spacy

spacy.load('xx')
```

Получаю:

```
spacy.lang.xx.MultiLanguage at 0x16d8fbc0da0
```

Делаю:

```
import spacy

nlp =spacy.load('en')
```

Получаю :

```
 module 'spacy.lang.en' has no attribute '__all__'
```

Как избавиться от ошибки?

---

Окружение:

Windows 10, Anaconda:

```
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py36_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.6                    py36_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py36_0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать это так:

1. запускаем `Anaconda prompt` *с правами администратора*. Дальше команды запускаем из под данного `Anaconda prompt`.
2. устанавливаем модуль `spacy`. В данном примере я буду устанавливать `spacy` в виртуальном окружении `py36`:

   ```
   conda install spacy -n py36 -y
   ```
3. устанавливаем окружение (`VirtualEnv`) `py36` и скачиваем все что нам нужно для `spacy`:

   ```
   activate py36
   python.exe -m spacy download en
   python.exe -m spacy download xx
   ```
4. запускаем iPython/Jupyter/Python из виртуального окружения `py36` для тестирования:

   ```
   In [1]: import spacy

   In [2]: spacy.load('xx')
   Out[2]: <spacy.lang.xx.MultiLanguage at 0x1a97c200588>

   In [3]: nlp =spacy.load('en')
   ```

   ---

> Как установить виртуальное окружение с использованием Anaconda?

1. запускаем `Anaconda prompt`:
2. создаем окружение (в данном примере будем использовать имя `py36`):

   ```
   conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda jupyter spacy nltk
   ```
3. [в данном ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685169/211923) показано как использовать виртуальные окружения

Comment: conda install spacy -n py36 -y

>>>EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\py36

Comment: Вот очень огромное вам спасибо! Упрямая SpaCy заработала, а у меня получилось пользоваьтся виртуальными средами. Единственное, что хотелось бы дополнительно уточнить  - ведь теперь весь мой код нужно будет перенести в эту среду и выполнять исключительно в ней? Еще раз  благодарю.

Comment: @Mar'yaMazaeva, да, вам понадобится запускать Python/Jupyter/iPython из данного вирт. окружения. В директории с Anaconda есть папка “envs” со всеми вирт. окружениями. В ней есть копии исполняемых файлов - Pyhon/Jupyter/etc. , вот ими и надо пользоваться