# Проблемы с установкой fbprophet

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pip, установка

При вызове команды "pip install fbprophet" выдаются следующие ошибки:

```
C:\Users\Usr>pip install fbprophet
Collecting fbprophet
  Using cached fbprophet-0.6.tar.gz (54 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.22 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.29.15)
Requirement already satisfied: cmdstanpy==0.4 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pystan>=2.14 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.19.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.0 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23.4 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: LunarCalendar>=0.0.9 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: convertdate>=2.1.2 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: holidays>=0.9.5 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools-git>=1.2 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23.4->fbprophet) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ephem>=3.7.5.3 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from LunarCalendar>=0.0.9->fbprophet) (3.7.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pymeeus<=1,>=0.3.6 in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from convertdate>=2.1.2->fbprophet) (0.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from holidays>=0.9.5->fbprophet) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib>=2.0.0->fbprophet) (41.2.0)
Installing collected packages: fbprophet
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Usr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nttrj5fb\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Usr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nttrj5fb\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q2i_9k2a\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\fbprophet'
         cwd: C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nttrj5fb\fbprophet\
    Complete output (45 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\fbprophet
    creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
    Importing plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nttrj5fb\fbprophet\setup.py", line 148, in <module>
        """
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nttrj5fb\fbprophet\setup.py", line 48, in run
        build_models(target_dir)
      File "C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nttrj5fb\fbprophet\setup.py", line 38, in build_models
        StanBackendEnum.get_backend_class(backend).build_model(target_dir, MODEL_DIR)
      File "C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nttrj5fb\fbprophet\fbprophet\models.py", line 206, in build_model
        import pystan
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pystan\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pystan.api import stanc, stan
      File "c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pystan\api.py", line 13, in <module>
        import pystan._api  # stanc wrapper
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Usr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nttrj5fb\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Usr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nttrj5fb\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q2i_9k2a\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\fbprophet' Check the logs for full command output.
```

pystan уже установлен, не могу понять, в чем проблема.

Comment: команда `import pystan` - отрабатывает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На официальном сайте `fbprohet` существует [заметка по установке `PyStan` на Windows](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html):

> On **Windows**, PyStan requires a compiler so you’ll need to [follow the
>   instructions](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html).
>   The easiest way to install Prophet in Windows is in Anaconda.

PS [связанный ответ показывающий как создать `conda environment` для задач по машинному обучению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685169/211923)

Answer (score 0):

Для установки fbProphet в W10 64x, без conda, Python3.7.4, мне помогли такие шаги:

CMD запущен с правами администратора.

- pip3 install Cython
- Download Visual C++ Build Tools installer and install it from here(выбрал все пункты при установке = 9Gb): http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe
- Go to this link and download the setup and install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145
- перезагрузка
- pip3 install pystan==2.17.1.0
- pip3 install fbprophet

Ссылки:

- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12016
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178281/installing-fbprophet-python-on-windows-10