# При запуске ошибки отсутствия модулей хотя все библиотеки подключены

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

Все библиотеки подключены к PyCharm. При запуске ругается на `matplotlib`, но если удалить эти библиотеки, то ничего не меняется.

Полный код (программа должна работать непосредственно с CSV файлом):

```
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as ply
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
fox_dataframe = pd.read_csv("sample_submission.csv", error_bad_lines=False, sep=",")
print('Считанный файл:\n', fox_dataframe)
print('Информация о стат. показателях:\n', fox_dataframe.describe())
print('Инфа по определенным столбцам:\n', fox_dataframe[['Patient_ID', 'Outcome']])
fox_dataframe['CopyS'] = fox_dataframe['Quality'].copy()
print('Создание нового столбца и копирование в него значений:\n', fox_dataframe)
print('Инфа по первым 10 записям:\n', fox_dataframe.head(10))
print('Инфа по последний 5 записям:\n', fox_dataframe.tail(5))
print('Сортировка первых 10 записей Patient ID \n', fox_dataframe.head(10).sort_values(by='Outcome'))
print('Инфа по 1-м двум строкам:\n', fox_dataframe.ilco[:2])
print('Инфа по последним дву строкам:\n', fox_dataframe.iloc[-2:])
```

Comment: советую сначала создать `conda virtual environment`, убедиться, что в этом окружении все работает, а после этого в настройках проекта в PyCharm указать в качестве `interpreter` - полный путь к `python` из заранее сконфигурированного `virtual env`

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

1. [Установите `Anaconda` и создайте `VirtualEnv`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685123/211923)
2. Убедитесь, что ваш скрипт правильно работает в созданном окружении
3. В конфигурации PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project: 'project_name' -> Python Interpreter справа добавить новый интерпретатор (`Add`) и в открывшемся окне выбрать `Conda Environment -> Existing Environment` выбрать путь к бинарному файлу `python` или `python.exe` (для Windows) из созданного окружения