# Ошибка установки implicit

Tags: python, windows, pip

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку implicit

pip install implicit выдаёт:

```
  Running setup.py clean for implicit
Failed to build implicit
Installing collected packages: implicit
    Running setup.py install for implicit ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\dalisalar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dalisalar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-70tjeaaa\\implicit_31c1c8a7b04c4e67af97ce15b1831ca6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dalisalar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-70tjeaaa\\implicit_31c1c8a7b04c4e67af97ce15b1831ca6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Dalisalar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dcr8so1j\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\dalisalar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\implicit'
         cwd: C:\Users\Dalisalar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-70tjeaaa\implicit_31c1c8a7b04c4e67af97ce15b1831ca6\
    Complete output (28 lines):
    c:\users\dalisalar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:642: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
      warnings.warn(
    c:\users\dalisalar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:642: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
      warnings.warn(
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit
    copying implicit\als.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit
    copying implicit\approximate_als.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit
    copying implicit\nearest_neighbours.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit
    copying implicit\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit
    copying implicit\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\cuda
    copying implicit\cuda\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\cuda
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\datasets
    copying implicit\datasets\lastfm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\datasets
    copying implicit\datasets\million_song_dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\datasets
    copying implicit\datasets\movielens.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\datasets
    copying implicit\datasets\reddit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\datasets
    copying implicit\datasets\sketchfab.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\datasets
    copying implicit\datasets\_download.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\datasets
    copying implicit\datasets\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\implicit\datasets
    running build_ext
    building 'implicit._als' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\dalisalar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dalisalar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-70tjeaaa\\implicit_31c1c8a7b04c4e67af97ce15b1831ca6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dalisalar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-70tjeaaa\\implicit_31c1c8a7b04c4e67af97ce15b1831ca6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Dalisalar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dcr8so1j\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\dalisalar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\implicit' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Установил Build Tools 14.2, перезагрузил. Проблема осталась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего будет [установить Anaconda](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685169/211923), [создать новое виртуальное окружение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002448/211923) и установить в это окружение модуль `implicit`, используя менеджер пакетов `conda`:

```
conda install implicit -c conda-forge -n <your_virtualenv_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Взгляните на эту строчку:
`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Вам тут ясно говорят что для установки этого модуля вам надо скачать
`Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2` или выше

Comment: В последнем предложении вопроса написано, что это сделано.

Comment: Да, увидел но хочу добавить. Если не получаеться то скачайте именно 14.2 версию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но читать я умею, и, как уже сказали, установил необходимую версию. Хотелось бы услышать что-то более конкретное.